# Enable Telerik Rad Grid Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: telerik, dotnetnuke, radgrid

I am trying to enable horizontal scrolling in telerik grid 
I followed the example from demo.telerik.com but had no luck
Here is my code . can anyone help me with this . 
by the way I am using telerik Grid In DNN with DnnGrid

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div>
        <dnn:dnngrid allowfilteringbycolumn="true"
            currentfilterfunction="Contains"
            onitemdatabound="grd_ItemDataBound"
            oncolumncreated="grd_ColumnCreated"
            cssclass="grid"
            id="grdWaitingForCommand"
            runat="server"
            autogeneratecolumns="true"
            allowmultirowselection="false"
            onitemcommand="grd_ItemCommand"
            width="800px">
                <ClientSettings EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true">
                    <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" 
                        UseStaticHeaders="True" 
                        SaveScrollPosition="true"></Scrolling>
                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                </ClientSettings>
                <HeaderStyle Width="225px"></HeaderStyle>
                <MasterTableView >
                    <Columns>
                        <dnn:GridTemplateColumn 
                            UniqueName="IndexColumn" 
                            HeaderText="ردیف" 
                            AllowFiltering="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="numberLabel" runat="server" Width="30px" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle Width="30px" />
                        </dnn:GridTemplateColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
            </dnn:dnngrid>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement. From our side the first part was to set the correct properties of the grid using the demo from Telerik. The next part was a javascript function, that was executing when the grid was created.

```
grid.ClientSettings.ClientEvents.OnGridCreating = "ShowHorizontalScroll"
```

The function sets overflow style to auto. You also may want to hide the vertical scrollbar because from what I remember, Telerik enables both horizontal and vertical scrollbars if you enable the feature.

The fix may not work in some browsers. The solution, that works for us, currently works on Chrome. Small changes may be needed to the styling if IE.

Now I saw, that the width of your column is smaller than the width of the grid. You can reduce the width of the grid or increase the width of the column and you should see the scroll.